# Haskell : list comprehension

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension

How can I write this code without repeating `(c !! x)` where is x = [0..7], using list comprehension is better but I couldn't figure how to write it

```hs
show (EOBoard f c r) = "EOBoard\n" ++ "Foundations "
   ++ show f ++ "\n" ++ "Columns \n" 
   ++ show (c!!0) ++ "\n" ++ show (c!!1) ++ "\n"
   ++ show (c!!2) ++ "\n" ++ show (c!!3) ++ "\n"
   ++ show (c!!4) ++ "\n" ++ show (c!!5) ++ "\n"
   ++ show (c!!6) ++ "\n" ++ show (c!!7) ++ "\n"
   ++ "Reserves " ++ show r
```

Comment: What is "where is x = [0..7]" supposed to mean?

Comment: C is a list which have 7 elements. And i want to print each one in new line

Comment: If you are assuming the list has (at least) 8 elements, then they should probably be stored as separate elements of the `EOBoard` value, rather than having to walk a linked list 8 times.

Answer (score 5):

Let's start by getting rid of all those manual line breaks.

```
import Data.List

show (EOBoard f c r) = intercalate "\n" $
  [ "EOBoard"
  , "Foundations " ++ show f
  , "Columns" 
  , show (c!!0)
  , show (c!!1)
  , show (c!!2)
  , show (c!!3)
  , show (c!!4)
  , show (c!!5)
  , show (c!!6)
  , show (c!!7)
  , "Reserves " ++ show r]
```

Note: if you want a line break at the end too, use `unlines` instead of `intercalate`.

As you noticed, there's a rather repetitive section. Also, those `!!` applications are kind of expensive. A list comprehension solves both problems, but I'd use `map` instead.

```
show (EOBoard f c r) = intercalate "\n" $
  [ "EOBoard"
  , "Foundations " ++ show f
  , "Columns" ] ++
  map show c ++
  ["Reserves " ++ show r]
```

(`map show c` could be replaced by `[show x | x <- c]` if you prefer.)

There's still something funny; `Show` really isn't for pretty-printing. `show` shouldn't insert line breaks. You probably actually want to write a custom pretty-printing function instead.

Comment: `unlines ["1","2"]` ==>
`"1\n2\n"` but the OP code does not have the trailing newline. so it's `intercalate` .

Comment: @WillNess, I didn't realize `unlines` was different from `unwords` in that regard. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What you wrote is equivalent to

```
show (EOBoard f c r) = "EOBoard\n" ++ "Foundations "
   ++ show f ++ "\n" ++ "Columns \n" ++
   ++ concat [ show s ++ "\n" | s <- take 8 c]
   ++ "\n" ++ "Reserves " ++ show r
```

which is equivalent to

```
show (EOBoard f c r) = "EOBoard\n" ++ "Foundations "
   ++ show f ++ "\n" ++ "Columns \n" ++
   ++ [ ch | s <- take 8 c, ch <- show s ++ "\n" ]
   ++ "\n" ++ "Reserves " ++ show r
```

or, using the `concat` more instead of inlining it, it is equivalent to

```
show (EOBoard f c r) = concat (
   [ "EOBoard\n", "Foundations ", show f, "\n", "Columns \n" ]
   ++ [ show s ++ "\n" | s <- take 8 c]
   ++ ["\n" , "Reserves " , show r] )
```

which is normally written with the `$` operator, as

```
show (EOBoard f c r) = concat $
   [ "EOBoard\n", "Foundations ", show f, "\n", "Columns \n" ]
   ++ [ show s ++ "\n" | s <- take 8 c]
   ++ ["\n" , "Reserves " , show r]
```

Comment: This time I think `unlines` is probably the way to go, or more generally `intercalate`.

Comment: @dfeuer no doubt, the LC does re-implement it, but the OP did ask for the LC solution, so. :)